# How to package MySQL with the Install4j does Install4j has the facility of creating Installers that can also install MYSQL

Tags: java, install4j, mysql-5.0

Does Install4J has the feature of installing MySQL 5.0 and the database i have created ,for my  Java Application on windows which is developed in Netbeans IDE 
Utimately what i need is  an .exe of my Java Application which is in Netbeans IDE and Installer that installs my Application into the clients system and the database created in MySQl .
Please Help with this

Comment: Please Help with this issue

Answer (score 1):

You could do this as part of a custom script to be run as part of your install but most likely you'd have to tailor it to each target environment. It would probably be a bit messy though as the installation process would vary wildly from Windows, to OSX, to Linux (and different Linux distros). Also, you'd have to deal with overwriting existing installations.

If you're code is database agnostic consider using something like http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html. It's pure Java (nothing to install besides adding JARs to your app), runs both in memory and persistent to disk, and feature rich. It would be much easier to deploy as you could have it save the database data in your apps install directory.

Comment: The Software which i am distributing to are all windows Users so i think there will be no problem with the platforms what i need is to install MySQL with my Application such that all my tables ,stored procedures and the data should get installed into it. And there will be no overwriting of existing Installations as the softwares what we are distributing will not be upgraded or any such cases. So Sir cud u please tell me the easy steps of integrating MySQL Database into install 4j with my Application

Comment: Please Help with the Issue

Answer (score 0):

Add the MySQL installer on Files->Distribution Tree and run it with a "Run executable" action after the "Install Files" action has run.

Probably there's an argument for running that installer in quiet mode and to modify parameters of the MySQL installation.